# Recognize multiple object using single xpath using attributes H3 and label text

Tags: xpath

I'm trying to recognize two objects on two different UI using a dynamic xpath.

So object are as in snippet:

```html
<div class="reports-filter">
  <ul id="portfolio-input--temp-ddisable">
 <li>
        <h3 class='reportOptions'><label>Enter Account Number</label></h3>
   <input id="name2" name="name2" type="text" value="" size="20"/>
 </li>
  </ul>
 <input type="hidden" name="secure" value="true"/>
</div>


<div class="multiCol">
     <h3 class='reportOptions'><label>Account Number&nbsp;</label></h3>
     <input id="reportFilters17.typeSpecific.string" name="reportFilters[17].typeSpecific.string" class="textFilter" type="text" value=""/>
       </div>
```

Now i tried used following xpath but to no luck

```
 //h3[contains(text(),'Account Number$']

 //h3[contains(.,'Account Number$']

 //h3[@class='reportOptions']

 //h3[@class='reportOptions']/text()

//label[contains(.,'Account Number$')]

.//*[contains(text(),'Account Number$')]
```

Comment: What is the expected result? Which objects are you trying to retrieve?

Comment: Why you put `$` at the end of string? It's not regex :) Remove it and watch the result

Comment: I did removed $ also and no use... I'm trying to identify both the objects using single xpath

Comment: `//h3[contains(.,'Account Number')]` works

Answer (score 0):

why are you using $ in contains function if you want to check end with number then use matches and second thing use `//h3[@class='reportOptions']/label` or `//h3[@class='reportOptions']/label/text()`

Comment: Removed $ and tried both and still not able to find the object

Comment: tried //label[contains(.,'Account Number')] &
//label[contains(text(),'Account Number')]